# Compare two numpy arrays row-wise ValueError

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compare two `NumPy` arrays row-wise and return the number of same rows.

If i use the code below:

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b=np.array([[1,4],[2,3]])
comp= np.logical_and(np.equal(a,b))
correct=numpy.sum(comp)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

However, this works:

```
np.logical_and([True, False], [False, False])
```

This is probably very silly but I am new to `NumPy`. Please help.

Comment: do you mean `np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])`?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone Yes! Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: `np.logical_and(*np.equal(a,b))`?

Comment: beat me too it on comments @zero323, write the soln and he can accept as answer ;(

Comment: You can also `print(np.logical_and.reduce(np.equal(a, b)).sum())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to extend the answer from @mgilson. You had the right idea, first you did this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,4],[2,3]])
np.equal(a, b)
>>>array([[ True, False],
   [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, you want to pass this to np.logical_and(), which if you look at the docs, it takes in two variables, x1 and x2 (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

So if you pass in the above array, you get the following:

```
np.logical_and(np.array([[True, False], [False, False]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

This is because np.array([[True, False], [False, True]]) is a single array, i.e, you only gave an x1 value, and did not give an x2 value. This is why the traceback tells you 'invalid number of arguments'. You need to give two values to this function.

@zero323 rightly gave you one solution, which is to just unpack the values into the function. More specifically, pass the first array value [True, False] into x1, and [False, False] into x2:

```
>>> np.logical_and(*np.equal(a, b))
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 15):

I think that you want something akin to:

```
np.sum(np.all(np.equal(a, b), axis=1))
```

which can shorthand to the following if you prefer:

```
np.sum(np.all(a == b, axis=1))
```

---

This will return `1` for:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [5, 6]])
```

but `0` for:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 3], [5, 6]])
```

Comment: `np.logical_and` does an element-by-element `and` for 2 arrays.  You're only passing it a single array (hence the `ValueError`).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'],\
                  ['e', 't'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']])
[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']
 ['e' 't']
 ['a' 'b']
 ['a' 'b']]

b = np.array([['a','b'],['e','t'],['r','t']])
[['a' 'b']
 ['e' 't']
 ['r' 't']]

shared_rows=0

for row in b:
    temp=a==row
    shared_rows+=sum(np.sum(temp, axis=1)==a.shape[1])

print(shared_rows)
4
```